# DropDownListFor not showing current value MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a drop down list, but I cannot get to show the current status in the view:

My html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => parts.Status, new { @class = "col-md-4" })

     //This shows the status as "New - Dispatch"
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => parts.Status, new { @class = "col-md-8 required-color" })

     //This shows as empty , but i want it to show as New - Dispatch
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => parts.Status, parts.StatusList, String.Empty, new { @class = "col-md-8 required-color" })
</div>
```

I'm getting my data from here:

```
StatusList = _partsRequestHServices.GetStatusList(parts.PartRequestStatus)
```

This is my List:

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetStatusList(string PartRequestStatus)
{
    List<SelectListItem> list = new System.Collections.Generic.List<SelectListItem>();
    list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "New - Dispatch", Value = "New - Dispatch"});
    list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Exception - Warehouse", Value = "Exception - Warehouse"});
    list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "HP Claim", Value = "HP Claim" });

    return list;
}
```

I want to show the current status in the view it works in the `TextBoxFor`, but not in the `DropDownListFor`.

Comment: One stupid assumption. Maybe it because Selected = false ?

Comment: Can you post your controller action that passed the model to the view as well?

Comment: StatusList = _partsRequestHServices.GetStatusList(parts.PartRequestStatus)

Comment: its working for the textbox for but not the dropdownlistfor

Comment: Your view code seems to suggest you are using this in a loop. If so you need to use a custom `EditorTemplate` and pass the `SelectList` as additional view data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return a `SelectList` not a generic `List<SelectListItem>()`.  By returning this kind of list you have the opportunity to set the value of the selected item.  Like this:

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetStatusList(string PartRequestStatus)
{
    list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "New - Dispatch", Value = "New - Dispatch", Selected = false });
    list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Exception - Warehouse", Value = "Exception - Warehouse", Selected = false });
    list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "HP Claim", Value = "HP Claim", Selected = false });   
}
```

Then consume that like this:

```
var statuses = GetStatusList("??");
SelectList statusList = new SelectList(statuses , "Id", "Text", selectedValue);
ViewData["Statuses"] = statusList;
```

Once you have this set up if you are using a custom template for your drop down list make sure your view model property for `Status` has this attribute:

```
[UIHint("string-name-of-editor-template")]
```

Comment: sorry i dont think this will work, what i dont understand is that its working for my textboxfor but not DropDownListFor.

Comment: Also I use this exact code in my MVC site.  Believe me, it works, I'm using it ...

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Selected = false` from your `SelectListItem`s (by using `Selected = false`, you are explicitly saying that you don't want any of them to be selected):

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetStatusList(string PartRequestStatus)
{
    List<SelectListItem> list = new System.Collections.Generic.List<SelectListItem>();
    list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "New - Dispatch", Value = "New - Dispatch" });
    list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Exception - Warehouse", Value = "Exception - Warehouse" });
    list.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "HP Claim", Value = "HP Claim" });

    return list;
}
```

Comment: i got rid of the Selected = false, but it still doesnt show the value